# dimensions for electrical outlet faceplate cutout

Tags: design

What are the dimensions for the cutouts in an electrical outlet faceplate?

I need to add several outlets in a sheet metal covering but I cannot find the dimensions or a dxf to use for the shape.  The closest I've found is the following image from http://www.archtoolbox.com/materials-systems/electrical/electricalfaceplates.html

The only problem is that it gives rectangular dimensions without providing the corner radius and spacing between the two outlets.

[image: faceplate dimensions]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/77960/are-all-rectangular-outlets-switches-and-plates-the-same-dimensions-and-interc

Comment: And: https://www.nema.org/Standards/Pages/Wiring-Devices-Dimensional-Specifications.aspx